# Simple question pertaining to LCM

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is the question I was trying to handle :

The LCM of two numbers is 48. The numbers are in ratio 2 : 3. The sum of number is ?

My attempt :

Prime factors of 48 : $2^4 * 3^1$ . Lets the numbers be : $2x$ and $3x$ . I could have solved it easy way using simple formula using $ HCF * LCM = Num1 * Num2 $  But I wanted to go other way around.

My analysis: since LCM contains $3^1$ , it must come from **either** number . since second number $3x$  contains $3$ , it is the one participation the $3$ in LCM . Then it's obvious $2^4$ comes from other number which is $2x$ , hence $x= 8$ . is my answer correct ?

Thanks

Comment: Are negative integers "numbers"?

Comment: " since LCM contains $3^1$, it must come from either number" should be "from at least one of the numbers".  Again, "it's obvious $2^4$ comes from other number" is not correct as the number may have a factor $2^m,0\le m\le 4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the numbers be $2x,3x\implies $ GCD $=x$

As you have rightly identified , the LCM is $\frac{\text{ Product}}{\text{ GCD }}=6x\implies 6x=48\implies x=8$

---

Alternatively,

let the numbers be $2^a3^b,2^c3^d$ where $a,b,c,d$ are non-negative integers.

So, $$\frac{2^a3^b}{2^c3^d}=\frac23\implies 2^a3^{b+1}=2^{c+1}3^d\implies a=c+1,d=b+1$$

lcm $(2^a3^b,2^c3^d)=$lcm$(2^{c+1}3^b,2^c3^{b+1})=2^{c+1}3^{b+1}$ which is equal to $48=2^43$

$\implies c+1=4,b+1=1$

Comment: Can you please forget the formula for the moment, go the analyzing way?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis, lcm $(2x,3x)=x\cdot$lcm$(2,3)=6x,$ right?

Comment: How did you take $x$ in `(2x,3x)=x⋅lcm(2,3)` simply out I am wondering . I am looking for concept which I am missing

Comment: @Mr.Anubis, consider real example with different combinations when $2,3$ divide $x$ and when they don't divide.

Comment: Proof (vii) of Article $9.1.12$ in http://bookos.org/book/1500438

Comment: Can you tell where my analysis which I posted in my answer is wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7874/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-mr-anubis)

Comment: My sincere apologies that I had suddenly came out of chat room since something urgent had came up.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis, anyway. Could I make it clear in the edited answer?

Comment: If I were just interested in solving the question, yes it helped . Did I learn something? , yes. But I still don't get the feeling , I want to know why my analysis doesn't work mainly and what should I consider in analysis to make it correct? . Thanks

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: The idea is good, the explanation I think is not clear enough. The power of $2$ that divides $2x$ is $1$ more than the power of $2$ that divides $3x$. Thus $2x$ is of the shape $2^4 k$. The only candidates are $2^4$ and $3\cdot 2^4$. You observed that $3$ divides $3x$, but that does not show that $3$ doesn't divide $2x$, in principle there could be a $3^1$ in each. However, if $3$ divides $2x$, then $3$ divides $x$, meaning that $9$ divides $3x$. This is false, since $9$ does not divide $48$. We conclude that $2x$ is indeed $16$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I just got the gist from your comment since it's very much cluttered and without symbols and little bit formal. I request you to please post an answer with in layman's term with simple language so I could learn and reason a bit . Thanks a lot )

Comment: @AndréNicolas also what did you mean by `The only candidates are 24 and 3⋅24` , where did they come from ? 2x and 3x?

Comment: The lcm ($48$) must be divisible by $2x$. We have already decided that $16$ divides $2x$. Since $\frac{48}{16}=3$, there are only $2$ multiples of $16$ that divide $48$, namely $16$ and $48$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ 48 = lcm(2n,3n) = lcm(2,3)\,n = 6n\iff n=8,\:$ by the distributive law for lcm.

Below is a proof of the distributive law $\rm\ lcm(ab,ac)\, =\, a\, lcm(b,c)$

$$\rm lcm(ab,ac)\mid n\iff ab,ac\mid n \iff b,c\mid n/a \iff lcm(b,c)\mid n/a \iff a\,lcm(b,c)\mid n$$

Answer (score 0):

since,the lcm of 2:3 is 48
therefore lcm of 2x and 3x is 6x 
6x=48 
x=8
2x=2*8=16
3x=3*8=24
the sum of no is 16+24=40

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The computations in your answer are hard to read. Please edit the post using the TeX syntax such as `$6x^2$`, which makes $6x^2$.